# como obtener datos mysql de una tabla y pasarlos a otra por php

Tags: php, mysql, html5, phpmyadmin

USO LA ULTIMA VERSIÓN DE PHP,
Hola que tal! tengo una pregunta!... como saco ciertos valores de una tabla, para meterla en otra?... ejemplo: tengo una tabla productos en esta tabla tengo..."ID", "producto", "descripcion" y "valor del producto" y ya tiene varios productos registrados adentro osea datos llenados

la otra tabla se llama inventario ... esta tabla tiene solamente "ID", "Producto", "Cantidad" y "suma de valor" en suma de valor si el producto vale $5 dolares y tengo 2 productos entonces en cantidad sale "2" y en suma de valores se suman cuanto cuesta en esta caso sera "$10" dolares.... y esta tabla la tengo que mostrar en un

como puedo hacer esto? Por favor! gracias!

y otra pregunta pequeña... como obtengo cuantas filas tengo en una tabla(solo el número de filas) y lo muestro en una etiqueta `html`, estoy intentando esto para ver si sale un numero pero no, no se como se hace, solo quiero que ese `echo` me muestre el numero de registros digamos un 8 y ya

```
$statement = $conexion->prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM carrito");
$statement->execute();
$resultado = $statement->fetchAll();
echo $resultado;
```

Comment: Como quieres meter los datos de la segunda tabla?, sería por formulario, a través de un csv,....

Comment: La respuesta a tu pregunta *pequeña*  es que uses `fetchColumn`. Por ejemplo: **`$resultado = $statement->fetchColumn();`**. Si no hay otro error, te imprimirá el valor de la única columna que devuelve tu consulta. La respuesta a tu pregunta *grande* es que revises el diseño de tus tablas. Es un grave error en muchos casos (y el tuyo es uno de esos), guardar datos calculados en una tabla. Cuando necesites contar o sumar datos lo puedes hacer en base a los valores, precios, cantidades que existan de esos datos. Almacenar esos datos calculados es costoso, ineficiente, innecesario.

Answer (score -1):

Para obtener el número de registros en una tabla se hace de la forma que mencionas, sólo que te falta asignar una variable que contará dichos registros.
Te comparto un ejemplo que tengo para que puedas aclarar tus dudas:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM usuarios";
            $sentencia = $conexion -> prepare($sql);
            $sentencia -> execute();
            $resultado = $sentencia -> fetch();

            $totalUsuarios = $resultado['total'];
```

fíjate que en total asigno el total de filas, puedes imprimirlo de la siguiente forma:

```
echo $resultato['total'];
```